# Way to connect oAuth2 services from local ui app from different url(localhost:4200) than backend with oAuth2(localhost:8080)

Tags: angular, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I have a RESTapi in springboot protected by third party oAuth2 sso and a ui with angular.RESTapi is working properly with oAuth2sso,now I am looking for a way to use it along with my angular app.
Currently Angular project is different than backend and don't want to put everything on single app.

Problem:When I am trying to connect from ui(localhost:4200) to backend(localhost:8080) it is not getting proper response as the request is referred from different origin than what i configured with oAuth2(localhost:8080).
By proper response i mean my app should redirect to oAuth2 login page(or use session to know logged-in user) when service get called and then redirect back with correct response to my ui app.

I may be wrong in designing this api(ps. need suggestions on how it can be corrected)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController("/api")
class SomeBackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SomeBackendApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/me")
    public String getUser() {
        return "John Doe";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried keeping nginx(proxy server) between your frontend and backend App?
Also you may need to add CORSConfiguration in your SecurityConfig file.

Comment: nginx is there already, no change;CORS config also added but no change.meanwhile got one suggestion that I should protect required pages of ui using authguard and angular-oauth2-oidc lib, and use that as session for backend services..